# '0 questions tagged' bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I've noticed that clicking on some tags takes me to a page that claims that *0 questions tagged exists*. One example: [memory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory).

[image]

**notes**:

- this bug occurs only when I'm logged in
- **related**: not all questions show when I click on their tags (EG: [linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) says it got 318 questions, but when I click on it, it shows 27.

Comment: Does this happen often? Can you take a screenshot next time? I've never seen that before

Comment: @mic it happens all the time; I've attached a screenshot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the "faq" tab of the "Tagged questions" page. There are [27 frequently asked questions tagged [linux]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux?sort=faq), but [322 (as of this writing) *total* questions tagged [linux]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux?sort=newest).

The same logic holds for the [memory] thing.

This only happens when you're logged in because the site remembers what tab you visited last, so in that case it shows you the faq, since that must be the last tab you clicked on; when you're offline, you just get the default.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's not so obvious. Usability issue then.

Comment: @Tshepang: Yeah, the bold/not bold distinction is quite subtle. I've pinged Jin to take a look at that, maybe he has an idea how to make it a little more obvious.